# Inserting data from PK to FK in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

In my 'person_address' I have 2 fk's coming from my person table ID and address table ID. In order to get these to update to the same values as my PK's in my database. I want to run something like:

```
command.Connection = conn;
command.CommandText = "insert into mydb.person values(null,'" + firstName.ToString() + "','" + lastName + "','" + telephoneV + "','" + emailAddress + "')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 


command.CommandText = "insert into mydb.address values(null,'" + addressV.ToString() + "','" + address2V + "','" + countyV + "','" + postcodeV + "','" + countryV + "')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //above sql statements insert variables into the database

command.CommandText = "insert into mydb.person_address values(null, null);";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Is this the correct way to use a 'joiner table'?

EDIT:

Attempted this and returned an error that address_addressID cannot be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not the correct way. null should not be inserted in PK. Make the PKs auto-incremented in your database.

Then get the last inserted id for both the queries as below.

```
long id1 = cmd1.LastInsertedId;
long id2 = cmd2.LastInsertedId;
```

Then insert both the ids as below

```
command.CommandText = "insert into mydb.person_address values("+id1+","+ id2+");";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```